# Accessory to raise handlebars (on a bmx)

Tags: maintenance, accessories, bmx

I just bought a used bmx bike and after raising the seat to a level where it is semi-comfortable to pedal while on the seat, I now find that the handlebars are too low.

Is there any sort of an after market accessory I could buy that could raise the handle bars up several inches?

UPDATE:
Here are some photos:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IEAw.jpg

Comment: That appears to be a threadless headset, but it's greatly complicated by the 360-degree brake adapter.  You could eliminate that feature and use one of the extension pieces discussed below, but I don't know how you'd raise the bars while preserving the current brake setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming you've already raised the handlebar as much as the obvious adjustments will allow.

There are solutions, but precisely which one depends on the style of the of the headset.  If you have an old style threaded headset then you need to replace the quill/stem with a new, taller one.  You can often, at the same time, get one that changes the "reach" of the bar, if you wish.  (But unfortunately the available selection of different old-style stems is small and getting smaller daily.)

For a newer threadless headset, you can get an extension to go on top of the steering tube to allow the stem to be mounted higher up, and/or you can replace the stem with one that rises at a steeper angle.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of headset it is; I added some photos, is it possible to tell from photos?

Comment: >I'm presuming you've already raised the handlebar as much as the obvious adjustments will allow.  >> No, I haven't; judging by the photos, is that actually possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to add spacers under your stem, get a top-load stem, and/or get taller bars. Also, keep in mind that bmx bikes aren't really designed for comfortable seated pedaling.